# Easiest way to plot a node structure which re-groups its nodes?

Tags: c#, winforms

The kind of structure I am talking about is shown in the picture below.

By now my DB contains each item with `giver_id (the previous item) | receiver_id (the next item)`. When I retrieve these items in-memory, I would like to show them in a meaningful way to the user.

I have researched and this seems to be called a "vertex/edge graph". The only option I've found is QuickGraph, and I don't seem to be able to implement it in my WindowsForm application (which is my other constraint).

Anybody knows about any other options to solve this problem?

Note: my solution does not need to be perfect, it will be used internally as a helper to configure the node chain in the DB.

[image]

Comment: You could use a [force-directed graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). A common way is to call [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), create the layout in text format and use the coordinates in your application.

Comment: Google for ".net graph layout" gets lots of results, whatever you use will need coding to get your data into the layout control.

Comment: I tried to follow both suggestions, but I could not implement any of them properly. I ended up implementing the following solution: 1) putting a web browser in my windows form, 2) choosing one of the gazillion "force directed graphs" in js (in my case: Springy.js), 3) formatting the js from the code. Easy as pie.